# Numbering the Grzegorczyk Hierarchy.

Tags: computability

I would like to know if there is a (known and maybe published) way to numbering, in a Gödel style, the functions belonging to every class in the Grzegorczyk Hierarchy and how could it be done.

Comment: This *might* be related: [Peter Hancock's web page on Skolem's problem](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/pgh/skolem.html)

Comment: To increase the integrity of this site, you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

I've found it! It 's developed in:

> Axt, P., Enumeration and the Grzegorczyk hierarchy, *Z. math. Logik und Grundl. Math.* 9 (1963) 53–65, [MR0144811](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=144811), [Zbl 0112.24602](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zbmath/search/?q=an%3A0112.24602), [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19630090106/abstract)